# Не открывается iframe при использовании :before

Tags: css, css3, telegram-bot, telegram, iframe

я использую [Telegram login widget](https://core.telegram.org/widgets/login) столкнулся с такой проблемой:

Widget генерируется и все на английском языке написано "Log with Telegram" хочу перевести это слово на русский, искал много способов особо почти все не рабочие и решил использовать :before чтобы накрыть поверх слово "Log with".

Все отлично работает **но при нажатии на надпись Вход через widget не открывается** а в остальном открывает без проблем как решить эту проблему ?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
.wptelegram-login-output-wrap:before {
    display: block;
    color: #fff;
    content: "Вход через";
    font-weight: bold;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 51px;
    margin-top: 12px;
    padding: 0.5px 4px 0px 0px;
    line-height: 15px;
    background-color: #000000;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте в стиль вашей надписи свойство `pointer-events: none;` чтобы событие курсора пробивало его до фрейма кнопки.

Answer (score 0):

```
.wptelegram-login-output-wrap:before {
    display: block;
    color: #fff;
    content: "Вход через";
    font-weight: bold;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 51px;
    margin-top: 12px;
    padding: 0.5px 4px 0px 0px;
    line-height: 15px;
    background-color: #000000;
    z-index:1; или z-index:-1;
```

}